# Show that $y^*(x)$ is increasing in $x$ if $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} > 0$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable with non-zero second partials. If for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists$ unique $y^*(x)$ that solves $\underset{y \in \mathbb{R}}{\max} f(x,y)$, then show that $y^*(x)$ is increasing in $x$ if $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} > 0$.

My observations:

$y^*(x)$ is determined from $f_y(x,y) = 0$ (as $f_{yy}$ must be negative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, $y^*(x)$ satisfies the first and second order conditions (note the assumption of non-zero second partials implies a strictly negative second partial derivative in $y$):

$$f_y(x,y^*(x))=0,\quad (1)\\
f_{yy}(x,y^*(x))<0.\quad (2)$$

Implicit differentiation of $(1)$ gives

$${y^*}'(x)=-{\partial_x f_y(x,y)\over \partial_y f_y(x,y)}\bigg|_{y=y^*(x)}=-{f_{yx}(x,{y^*}(x))\over  f_{yy}(x,y^*(x))}>0.$$

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed implicit differentiation of that term. Sometimes, these things just don't strike!